# Debian 9 application can't access external url

Tags: debian, sudo, internet

I have a strange issue on my Debian 9 (KDE as window manager) : when I open an app like Telegram, Gitkraken or Atom, I can't access the internet externally; I get the error :

"impossible to connect to the host , the connection to the proxy server has been closed" from "KIO Client" (translated from french)

When I launch my apps with the sudo comand, the internet can be reached. I don't really like launching my apps with sudo, can you help me out?

Comment: I don't think it's a vendor problem, i have internet with firefox for example. It may be a privilege problem, and I never used privilege much.
(or did I misunderstood your reply?)

Comment: Forget my comments, the question of things working as sudo is a good clue.

Comment: see my answer, reread your question better.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to add the solution, but accept the answer that helped you to resolve the problem or post a self answer (you need to wait a day before you can accept it), so question and answer are separated.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have setup a (wrong?) proxy variable in your user, or you setup it up in another different network and is not working in the current.

You get way running software as root (sudo), because the `root` user environment is then different, and then a proxy is not defined. (btw, you should not run a browser as root, it is insecure)

Search in you user startup scripts for `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` directives, and comment them out.

Alternatively, you may have setup a proxy in the interface of some specific software.

Comment: I don't use my browser on sudo, only my atom/gitkraken/telegram. I can access internet with my firefox as default user.

In my /etc/profile, i don't have any ```http_proxy``` or https directives

Comment: The same comments apply to atom/gitwhatever/telegram.